# SwiftUI ForEach for preview and print Device name

Tags: swift, swiftui

I am trying to print the device name while it generates the SiftUI for preview.

Below code works completely fine.

```
struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        ForEach(["iPhone SE","iPhone 11 Pro Max","iPhone SE"], id: \.self) { (deviceName)  in

            LandmarkList().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
        }
    }
}
```

How do I print the device name while it generates the preview. Is it like print can't be written in this closure . Below is the code which does not work

```
struct LandmarkList_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {

        ForEach(["iPhone SE","iPhone 11 Pro Max","iPhone SE"], id: \.self) { (deviceName)  in
          print("device name\(deviceName)")
            return LandmarkList().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a code that works

```
static var previews: some View {
    ForEach(["iPhone SE","iPhone 11 Pro Max","iPhone SE"], id: \.self) { deviceName -> AnyView in
        print("device name\(deviceName)")
        return AnyView(TestPublishBridging().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName)))
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Print will not work here. You can rather just go this way for debugging

```
    let deviceArray = ["iPhone SE","iPhone 11 Pro Max","iPhone SE"]


    VStack(){
        ForEach(self.deviceArray, id: \.self) { deviceName in
          Text(deviceName) // for debugging purpose
            return LandmarkList().previewDevice(PreviewDevice(rawValue: deviceName))
        }

    }
```

Refer to the following for better understanding

[Array.forEach creates error "Cannot convert value of type '()' to closure result type '_'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56916079/array-foreach-creates-error-cannot-convert-value-of-type-to-closure-result/56916341)